# got a error message saying No connection

Tags: php, mysql

I got a error message saying "No connection":

> Warning: mysql_connect(): No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. in C:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\memberSystemBasic\memberSystemBasic\connect_to_mysql.php on line 18`
>
> No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

Please help me on this one. Thank you.

Comment: is the mysql server running ? did you set host,username,password etc. values for the mysql server correctly ?

Comment: Only hostname/port is relevant. If the user data incorrect, he would get a different message.

Comment: [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Comment: I wold request you to go through these links solution https://www.google.co.in/#q=no+connection+could+be+made+because+the+target+machine+actively+refused+it.+php

Answer (score 2):

If the Database-Server refuse the connection, the Database-Server is not listen to the public (and you try to connect external). Use `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` for local connections. Otherwise your Database-Server is not started - Go to your **XAMPP Control Panel** and start the MySQL Server!

To enable external Database-Access, comment out the line `bind-address = 127.0.0.1` in `my.cnf`

If you don't have access to the server configuration, **contact** your server administrator.

**Information:**

`mysql_*` has marked as **DEPRECATED**, please use [`PDO`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php) or [`MySQLi`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)